# powershell mandatory parameter throws error when null

Tags: powershell

I am confused about how to do error handling in the case that a mandatory variable remains null.

```
function parse-com{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$list
     )
...
```

In this case if no argument is passed for $list then I am prompted for it, but if I just hit enter (pass a null to $list) then I throw an error. What I would rather do is throw a usage statement and/or exit gracefully. Example...

```
PS C:\Users\memyself> parse-com
cmdlet parse-com at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
list[0]: 
parse-com : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'list' because it is an empty array.
At line:1 char:1
+ parse-com
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [parse-com], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyArrayNotAllowed,parse-com
```

Comment: Look into using a [ValidateScript](https://powershell.org/2013/05/21/validatescript-for-beginners/) on the parameter instead of merely making it mandatory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When passing a `$null` value, that satisfies the `Mandatory` requirement. If you want the command then to fail prior to execution then you should use validation as @JeffZeitlin suggests.

It sounds like what you need to validate is that the value is not `$null` nor is it an empty array. For which you could user `[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]`

```
function parse-com{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string[]]$list
    )
```

Comment: I had high hopes, but I cannot really see that it does anything other than throw a different error.

Comment: `PS D:\MyCOMTracker> D:\MyCOMTracker\parse-com.ps1
cmdlet parse-com.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
list[0]: 
D:\MyCOMTracker\parse-com.ps1 : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'list'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument 
collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the command again.
  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [parse-com.ps1], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,parse-com.ps1`

Comment: @klaypigeon The point of the `Validate` is to throw that error before the command executes. If you want to just accept a null value, then take out the `mandatory` and the `validate` and you'll have to write your own logic around what to do when the parameter is `$null` inside the function.

Comment: This answer is wrong and misleading, as `Mandatory` already implies not `$null` or empty. That's why the options `AllowNull` or `AllowEmptyString` exist for `Mandatory` parameters. See their description in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6. Solving OPs problem needs a different streak, like e.g. making the parameter non-mandatory or check from the calling site.

Comment: But `ValidateNotNullOrEmpty` can be used to check untyped parameters or parameters which accept `$null`. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-6#validatenotnull-validation-attribute